# Websphere MQ - MQQueueManager, keep it open or close after every connection

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have a C# application that connects to a Websphere MQ.

Basically:

```
 MQEnvironment.Hostname = HostName;
 MQEnvironment.Channel = Channel;
 MQEnvironment.Port = Port;
 MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName);

 using (MQQueue putQueue = queueManager.AccessQueue(putQueueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT))
 { 
 }
```

My question is: Should I create only one instance of the MQQueueManager for the whole application and reuse it everytime I want to put a message or create new MQQueueManager object(connection) for every call?

Comment: I implement MqManager as singleton and do not have any problems with it. Is your question performance related or something else?

Comment: No, I don't have a performance issue. Just wondered what is the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your are sharing connections, create MQQueueManager instance once per thread and keep it as long as you need, call the Disconnect method when your job is done. Don't keep the instance till end of your application.

Similarly for queue, open queue once and keep putting/getting messages and once job done, close the queue.

Read this article ob MQ Best practices: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0807_hsieh/0807_hsieh.html

Comment: outside of connection pooling is there any other way of increasing performance when creating a new connection/MQQueueManager per request thread ?

Comment: I have to make multiple connections to seceral Queue Manager. What's the best practice for the object `MQQueue`. set up and keep the connection as singleton during the whole application life cycle and disposing the connection when application is shutting down?